# 'Incomplete type' error declaring pointer-to-member function template parameter for std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

Here's the declaration:

```
#include <functional>    

class A { ... };

double fA( std::function<double((A::*)(double))> fp) { ... }
```

which gives me error

> In function ‘double fA(std::function)’:
>   tb.cpp:32:8: error: ‘fp’ has incomplete type

Though there is no problem with

```
double fA( double ((A::*fp)(double)) ) { ... }
```

What's the right way to supply this type as a template parameter to `std::function`?

Comment: There's probably a better way, but you can take out the `A::*` and use `std::bind` to bind the object as the `this` argument: http://liveworkspace.org/code/dcd70739787666936ab49df680cc92ea

Comment: @chris Thanks, that's a good idea.  But I have a lot of instances of 'bar' and so I'd like the `<functional>` magic to happen in `fA`.  But I'm going to look into your solution as well.

Comment: How did you want to call `fA` to distinguish instances?

Comment: Another option along those lines that you might find a bit better is to change the signature to `double fA(std::function<double(A &, double)> fp, A &thisArg)` and call `fp(thisArg, whateverDouble)` inside of `fA`. That way you can call `fA` by saying `A a; fA(&A::foo, a);`. Here's [what I mean](http://liveworkspace.org/code/616d3f7d98ebb9961fffa96e39bcb407) for that.

Comment: @chris Well this is just a extremely simplified version of more complex code, basically the instance in question would be known to `fA` by `fA` being in its scope, rather than being passed as a separate parameter.  But I might go with passing it as a parameter actually, then binding along your lines probably would be the right thing to do.  To keep my options open though and just for general knowledge I'd like to know the answer to the question as asked, unless it really is ill-posed (doesn't seem that way to me now though).

Comment: @chris Posted the last comment before I saw your 3rd.  The thing with that is that the arguments of `fp` are already defined, can't change those.

Comment: @chris If you want to put your comments into an answer I'll give it to you, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing something very similar to @chris's suggestion, the code from his example is the following:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct S {
   void foo() {std::cout << i;};
   int i;
};

void bar(std::function<void()> func) {
    func();
}

int main() {
   S s1, s2;
   s1.i = 5;
   s2.i = 6;

   bar(std::bind(&S::foo, s1));
   bar(std::bind(&S::foo, s2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure of what you really want. The argument to `std::function` must be a free function signature as stated in the standard:

```
template<class R, class... ArgTypes>
class function<R(ArgTypes...)>;
```

Note that the argument is the signature of the `operator()` that will be offered by the function object. It cannot be a *pointer-to-member* to a different type, it is just the return type and the arguments to the `std::function<>` object being created.

The extra set of parenthesis in the function declaration could indicate that you actually want to create a `std::function` function object that takes as argument a pointer to member and returns a `double`. If that is the case, the signature of the argument to the `std::function` is missing the return type:

```
std::function<double (void (A::*)(double))> fp;
```

Which could be initialized with:

```
double myfunc( void (A::*mptr)(double) ) {}
// ...
fp = myfunc;
```